# CSS: Grouping of declarations

Tags: css, css-selectors

The declarations for `.box1` etc. are grouped in the example below.

Can the same be done for `.box1 a` etc. too?

```
.box1, .box2, .box3 {
   color: red; }

.box1 a {
   text-decoration:none; }

.box2 a {
   text-decoration:none; }

.box3 a {
   text-decoration:none; }
```

> **Note:** I don't mean `box1 a, box2 a, box3 a`, is there something simpler than that?

Answer (score 2):

## Matches

There are many ways to shorten this CSS:

```
.box1 a, box2 a, box3 a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

However, most require more HTML. The [`:matches`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/) pseudo-class is the only way without adding more classes. Here's how it looks:

```
:matches(.box1, .box2, .box3) a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

---

## Other methods

However, this doesn't really work when your HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="box1"><a href="..."></a></div>
<div class="box2"><a href="..."></a></div>
<div class="box3"><a href="..."></a></div>
<div class="box4"><a href="..."></a></div>
<div class="box5"><a href="..."></a></div>
```

If you glance at this, you will probably assume that all of these get about the same styling and with slight styling differences, that's a problem if someone wants to edit your code. Why not just add another class to all of the elements that you want to be affected? This is what it'll become:

#### CSS

```
.container-box a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

#### HTML

As an added benefit, the HTML is more telling too:

```
<div class="box1 container-box"><a href="...">...</a></div>
<div class="box2 container-box"><a href="...">...</a></div>
<div class="box3 container-box"><a href="...">...</a></div>
<div class="box4">...</div>
<div class="box5">...</div>
```

It's obvious that the first three boxes have more styles than the last 2.

Yes, complex selectors are needed, **but** another class simplifies CSS and makes it easier to tell which elements are affected.

---

### Tag Selector

```
div a {
  ...
}
```

#### HTML

This will select all divs with an `a` tag inside so if you have all your divs have `a` tags inside, don't use this. However, the HTML will look like this:

```
 <div class="box1"><a href="...">...</a></div>
 <div class="box2"><a href="...">...</a></div>
 <div class="box3"><a href="...">...</a></div>
 <div class="box4">...</div>
 <div class="box5">...</div>
```

---

### Container

You also can make a container for the elements and select them that way.

#### CSS

```
.container div a {
  ...
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="container>
  <div class="box1"><a href="..">...</a></div>
  <div class="box2"><a href="..">...</a></div>
  <div class="box3"><a href="..">...</a></div>
</div>
<div class="box4">...</div>
<div class="box5">...</div>
```

Again it's obvious which are being selected and which aren't.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use `:matches`.

```
:matches(.box1, .box2, .box3) a { text-decoration: none; }
```

Here is the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#matches-pseudo). Here's an [article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/m/matches/) about `:matches`. Here's the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:any), which refers to it as `:any`, since at the moment it is available under the vendor-prefixed versions `:-moz-any` and `:-webkit-any`. Having to write out both of those sort of defeats the point of saving keystrokes, though.

If you are drinking the CSS pre-processor Kool-Aid, then in most of them you can do `.box1, .box2, .box3 { a { text-decoration-none; } }`.

You could also in theory use XPath (via `document.evaluate`), with an expression such as

```
//input[matches(@id, 'left\d*right')]
```

That is XPath 2.0 which might or might work in your browser's version of `document.evaluate`. In XPath 1.0, you'd need an ugly workaround:

```
//*[starts-with(@id, 'left') and ends-with(@id, 'right') and 
  boolean(number(substring-before(substring-after(@id, "left"), "right"))]
```

Comment: I guess there is a `not` missing in `XPath 2.0 which might or might work` :)?